# Providing third-party dependencies in CMake project

Tags: cmake

My CMake-based C++ project uses a third-party library. It is relying on that this library is installed. I'd like to include or add the third-party library in some way into my project. How can I achieve that?

Comment: "Is that valid?" Well that depends on many issues. Among them, licensing and maintenance is the two biggest. Do the license between your project and the third-party library match or are compatible? Or do you have a license to include the library in your project like that? And how will you handle maintenance, updates and patches for the third-party library?

Comment: use conan or some other package manager to install libraries and build them in your build pipeline

Comment: Question title does not match question content. "How to make project portable" is even boarder topic than "how to use some third-party library". And in both cases there is no universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

For external project that are available with their source code, use CMake's external project, cf. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html
With that you can automatically download and compile external project. Then you can use them like an internal library and you can install them together with your library, if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the licence you can add the compiled library, too. Thus your user does not need to compile by it self, which can save a lot of trouble.

Comment: bad idea if portable means multi platform (e.g. macos, linux, android, windows)

Comment: Not so bad in case bundles for some major platforms are provided. I know multiple open source applications working in this way, e.g. cmake.